# Why would using the same dataset for training and testing gives different accuracies?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been looking into the loss function of the training and the validation dataset, and I keep seeing the validation loss being smaller than the training loss, even when they are the same data set. I'm trying to get some insight as to why this would be the case.

I am training a model in tensorflow to predict some time series data.
Consequently, the model creation and preprocessing is as follows:

```
window_size = 40
batch_size  = 32
forecast_period = 6
model_name = "LSTM"
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

_seed = 42
tf.random.set_seed(_seed)

def _sub_to_batch(sub):
    return sub.batch(window_size, drop_remainder=True)

def _return_input_output(tensor):
    _input  = tensor[:, :-forecast_period, :]
    _output = tensor[:, forecast_period:, :]
    return _input, _output

def _reshape_tensor(tensor):
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=-1)
    tensor = tf.transpose(tensor, [1, 0, 2])
    return tensor


# total elements after unbatch(): 3813
train_ts_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_ts)\
                            .window(window_size, shift=1)\
                            .flat_map(_sub_to_batch)\
                            .map(_reshape_tensor)\
                            .map(_return_input_output)
#                             .unbatch().shuffle(buffer_size=500, seed=_seed).batch(batch_size)\
#                             .map(_return_input_output)

valid_ts_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(valid_ts)\
                            .window(window_size, shift=1)\
                            .flat_map(_sub_to_batch)\
                            .map(_reshape_tensor)\
                            .unbatch().shuffle(buffer_size=500, seed=_seed).batch(batch_size)\
                            .map(_return_input_output)

def _forecast_mae(y_pred, y_true):
    _y_pred = y_pred[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    _y_true = y_true[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    mae = tf.losses.MAE(_y_true, _y_pred)
    return mae

def _accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
    # print(y_true) => Tensor("sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1:0", shape=(None, 34, 1), dtype=float32)
    # y_true[-forecast_period:, :]  =>   Tensor("strided_slice_4:0", shape=(None, 34, 1), dtype=float32)
    # y_true[:, -forecast_period:, :] => Tensor("strided_slice_4:0", shape=(None, 6, 1), dtype=float32)

    _y_pred = y_pred[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    _y_pred = tf.reshape(_y_pred, shape=[-1, forecast_period])
    _y_true = y_true[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    _y_true = tf.reshape(_y_true, shape=[-1, forecast_period])

    # MAPE: Tensor("Mean_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
    MAPE = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs((_y_pred - _y_true) / _y_true), axis=1, keepdims=True)

    accuracy = 1 - MAPE
    accuracy = tf.where(accuracy < 0, tf.zeros_like(accuracy), accuracy)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(accuracy)
    return accuracy

model = k.models.Sequential([
    k.layers.Bidirectional(k.layers.LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, 1)),
    k.layers.Bidirectional(k.layers.LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True)),
    k.layers.TimeDistributed(k.layers.Dense(1))
])

model_name = []
model_name_symbols = {"bidirectional": "BILSTM_1", "bidirectional_1": "BILSTM_2", "time_distributed": "td"}
for l in model.layers:
    model_name.append(model_name_symbols.get(l.name, l.name))

model_name = "_".join(model_name)
print(model_name)

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_ts_dataset):
    print(i, x.numpy().shape, y.numpy().shape)
```

The output of the shapes of the datasets is as follows:

```
BILSTM_1_BILSTM_2_td
0 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
1 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
2 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
3 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
4 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
5 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
6 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
7 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
8 (123, 34, 1) (123, 34, 1)
```

then:

```
_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S")
_log_dir = os.path.join(".", "logs", "fit7", model_name, _datetime)

tensorboard_cb = k.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=_log_dir)

model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=[_forecast_mae, _accuracy])

history = model.fit(train_ts_dataset, epochs=100, validation_data=train_ts_dataset, callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])
```

I've been looking into the loss function of the training and the validation dataset, and *I keep seeing the validation loss being smaller than the training loss.* I could be underfitting. However, I replaced the validation set with the training set as a simple test to monitor the loss and accuracy while training and testing. But I'm still getting validation accuracy being greater than the training one. Below is the accuracy across the training and the validation datasets:

[image]

To me its very weird I'm getting a validation accuracy that is greater than the training accuracy though I'm using the same dataset for training and testing. And there is no dropout, no batchNormalization layer etc...

Any hint on what could be the reason for this behavior? That would be much appreciated!!

===================================================================

Here are made some modification to the code to check if the batch size has any effect or not. Additionally, in order to remove any doubts in the `tf.data.Dataset`, I used numpy arrays as input. Hence the new code is as follows:

```
custom_train_ts   = train_ts.transpose(1, 0)[..., np.newaxis]
custom_train_ts_x = custom_train_ts[:, :window_size, :] # size: 123, window_size, 1
custom_train_ts_y = custom_train_ts[:, -window_size:, :] # size: 123, window_size, 1

custom_valid_ts   = valid_ts.transpose(1, 0)[..., np.newaxis]
custom_valid_ts_x = custom_valid_ts[:, :window_size, :]
custom_valid_ts_y = custom_valid_ts[:, -window_size:, :]
custom_valid_ts   = (custom_valid_ts_x, custom_valid_ts_y)
```

Secondly, in order to make sure that the accuracy is calculated over the entire dataset, and not dependent on the batch size, I fed in the dataset as is, without batching. Additionally, I implemented a custom metric as follows:

```
def _accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    # print(y_true) => Tensor("sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1:0", shape=(None, 34, 1), dtype=float32)
    # y_true[-forecast_period:, :]  =>   Tensor("strided_slice_4:0", shape=(None, 34, 1), dtype=float32)
    # y_true[:, -forecast_period:, :] => Tensor("strided_slice_4:0", shape=(None, 6, 1), dtype=float32)

    _y_pred = y_pred[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    _y_pred = tf.reshape(_y_pred, shape=[-1, forecast_period])
    _y_true = y_true[:, -forecast_period:, :]
    _y_true = tf.reshape(_y_true, shape=[-1, forecast_period])

    # MAPE: Tensor("Mean_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
    MAPE = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs((_y_pred - _y_true) / _y_true), axis=1, keepdims=True)

    accuracy = 1 - MAPE
    accuracy = tf.where(accuracy < 0, tf.zeros_like(accuracy), accuracy)        
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(accuracy)
    return accuracy


class MyAccuracy(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.accuracy_function = _accuracy
        self.y_true_lst = []
        self.y_pred_lst = []

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.y_true_lst.append(y_true)
        self.y_pred_lst.append(y_pred)

    def result(self):
        y_true_concat = tf.concat(self.y_true_lst, axis=0)
        y_pred_concat = tf.concat(self.y_pred_lst, axis=0)
        accuracy = self.accuracy_function(y_true_concat, y_pred_concat)
        self.y_true_lst = []
        self.y_pred_lst = []
        return accuracy
    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}
```

Finally, model compile and fit as:

```
model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(hparams["learning_rate"]), 
              metrics=[tf.metrics.MAE, MyAccuracy()])

history = model.fit(custom_train_ts_x, custom_train_ts_y, epochs=120, batch_size=123, validation_data=custom_valid_ts, 
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])
```

And when I looked into the training and the validation accuracy in tensorboard I got the following:

[image]

Therefore, clearly, this doesn't make any sense. Additionally, in this case, I make sure that calculate the accuracy only one, at the end of the epoch after calling the `result()`. However, when looking into the validation loss, I found that the training loss is lower than the validation loss:

[image]

Comment: hello! I made some edits to your question because the way it was initially put together the actual question was kind of buried in the middle.  With a long question with lots of setup generally you get better retention when you present the root question concisely near the beginning then work your way back to it with the explanation.  If you want to make further edits please do! I mostly duplicated one paragraph to the beginning so there may be a better way of writing it. Hope you get an answer (I look forward to seeing it) Cheers!

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, Thank you for reviewing my question. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: As far as I understand - metrics are averaged for all batches in the epoch. I think that sometimes in the training process the model may be in very bad state resulting in significant loss. But such events are rare and usually validation is measured when a model is in a good state.

Comment: I am not sure but I think training accuracy is accumulated through out learning phase which update model's parameter constantly. On the other hand, validation accuracy is measure after each learning phase (model weight is freeze). I think you could verify this by freezing model's weight (so there will be no parameter update during training phase, by set `layer.trainable = False`) and use the same datasets for training and validation

Comment: @Wakeme UpNow Difference is too big to be explained by that. If it was a reason - then we would see validation accuracy for epoch equal to training accurancy on the next epoch

Comment: Does difference between accuracies for train and validation depend on batch_size? My guess is that the larger the batch, the smaller this difference gets

Comment: @user13044086, I believe you're correct. So I increased the batch size to the maximum and I got them both almost overlapping. Can you please provide some more details on the difference between training and testing when calculating the loss and accuracy? Much thank you in advance!!

Comment: The intuition is that the model changes from one batch to another during training. Loss is computed for each batch and then these losses are aggregated to compute total loss for an epoch. If you set batch size to maximum, then you compute training loss only once for each epoch. So it should be basically the same as validation loss if you validate on training. The difference appears, when there are several batches, because aggregation of separate losses doesn't sum up to the total loss. But currently I try to figure out, why the aggregated loss happens to be substantially higher than total loss

Comment: @user13044086 please post your insight as an answer. It helps the site when answer like content is posted in answers (not to mention the bounty :)

Comment: The last chart looks very strange because training loss for epoch is calculated immediately after calculating validation loss for the previous epoch based on the same data and model state. They should be equal. Could you add manual calculation of loss before and after calling fit (call model and calculate loss) ?

Comment: are you using a smaller dataset?

Answer (score 1):

They are different because optimizer updates the parameters at the end of each batch and the `val_loss` will be computed at the end, but the `train_loss` will be computed in the process.

Even if you just have one sample in a batch and just one batch in each epoch, they will differ from each other because the network will do the forward pass for your sample and compute the loss which will be called `train_loss` and after updating the parameters it will compute the loss again and this time it will be called `val_loss` (in this case your next epochs `train_loss` will be equal to your current `val_loss`).

So if you want to check if what I just said is true, you can simply set the `learning_rate` of your optimizer to `0`, then you'll get the same loss.

And here is the code I've tested for the same problem on MNIST (temporarily you can view the code and the results on my colab from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L1xNZFVY6Gh5q_Q8W6diRztbaGFVDGgA?usp=sharing)):

```py
# ---------------------------------
# Importing stuff
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

from keras.utils import to_categorical

# ---------------------------------
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# one-hot
trainy = to_categorical(trainy, 10)
testy = to_categorical(testy, 10)

# image should be in shape of (28, 28, 1) not (28, 28)
trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, -1)
testX = np.expand_dims(testX, -1)

# normalize
trainX = trainX/255.
testX = testX/255.

# ---------------------------------
# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(trainX.shape[1:]))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Compile and fit for several scenarios:

```py
# training on 1 sample, but with learning_rate != 0
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

batchX = trainX[0].reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
batchy = trainy[0].reshape(1, 10)

model.fit(batchX, batchy, validation_data = (batchX, batchy), batch_size = 1, 
          shuffle = False, validation_batch_size = 1, epochs = 5)

# You will see that the loss and val_loss are different and the
# next steps loss is equal to the current steps val_loss
```

```py
# training on 1 sample, with learning_rate == 0
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

batchX = trainX[0].reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
batchy = trainy[0].reshape(1, 10)

model.fit(batchX, batchy, validation_data = (batchX, batchy), batch_size = 1, 
          shuffle = False, validation_batch_size = 1, epochs = 5)

# You will see that the loss and val_loss are equal because 
# the parameters will not change
```

```py
# training on the complete dataset but with learning_rate != 0
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data = (trainX, trainy), batch_size = 32, 
          shuffle = False, validation_batch_size = 32, epochs = 5)

# this is similar to the case you asked
```

```py
# training on the complete dataset and learning_rate == 0
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data = (trainX, trainy), batch_size = 32, 
          shuffle = False, validation_batch_size = 32, epochs = 5)

# set the learning_rate to zero and again you'll get loss == val_loss
```

Comment: I can't understand the downvote, at least someone explain what's wrong with my answer :/